# Parsing to different types of values in boost::spirit and apply casting to negative numbers

Tags: c++, boost-spirit, boost-spirit-qi

I am trying to solve an issue with positive and negative values in Boost Spirit.

The parser should use unsigned numbers (positive) 99% of the time.

The program works reading a string that defines a variables from 1 to 32 bits that should be read from another stream (for question context, not shown in the example), but there is a special case where a string "D_REF" may be a 16 bits signed number (2's complement).

The program codifies all checks as unsigned values in a `std::vector`, so I need to codify that positive value as unsigned, but previously I need to apply a cast to it to force it into an unsigned short value, and then store it in the unsigned int struct.

This need comes from an after request where a data stream shall be read and values extracted from it as unsigned, and there parsed comparisons apply to them.

I know this request may look weird, but it is a must for a current project, so can anyone help me with this?

Godbolt link: https://godbolt.org/z/8j615Mecx

```
//#define BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

namespace engine
{
    struct Check
    {
        std::string variable;
        unsigned int number;
    };

    using Checks = std::vector<Check>;
}

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(engine::Check, variable, number)

namespace engine
{
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

    template <typename It>
    class Parser : public qi::grammar<It, Checks()>
    {
    private:
        qi::rule<It, Check(), qi::blank_type> equal1, equal2;
        qi::rule<It, Checks()> start;

    public:
        Parser() : Parser::base_type(start)
        {
            using namespace qi;

            //equal1 = as_string["MSG33.D_REF"] >> "==" >> int_[static_cast<unsigned short>(_1)];// This is the idea...
            equal1 = as_string["MSG33.D_REF"] >> "==" >> int_;// This may contain negative numbers, but they are only 16 bits length, so they must be casted to "unsigned short" and not to "unsigned int"
            equal2 = +(alnum | char_("._")) >> "==" >> uint_;

            start = skip(blank)[(equal1 | equal2) % "&&"] > eoi;
        }
    };

    Checks parse(const std::string& str)
    {
        using It = std::string::const_iterator;
        static const Parser<It> parser;

        Checks checks;

        It first = str.begin(), last = str.end();
        if (!qi::parse(first, last, parser, checks))
            return {};

        return checks;
    }
}

int main()
{
    auto checks1 = engine::parse("MSG33.ANYTHING == 25");// Normal case. All the checks are done with positive variable values
    auto checks2 = engine::parse("MSG33.D_REF == 25");// Especial case extended from normal case. Checks A positive/negative variable with a positiove value.
    auto checks3 = engine::parse("MSG33.D_REF == -25");// Especial case. Check a negative value. D_REF should be codified as 2's complement 16 bits unsigned, but it is converted to 32 bits unsigned
    
    std::cout << std::hex << "Obtained: " << checks3.front().number << std::endl << "Wished: " << static_cast<unsigned short>(checks3.front().number);// It displays 0xffffffe7, but I need 0xffe7. Possible semanatic action to force conversion prior to vector insertion???
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### First: A word of caution

Automatic attribute propagation already does exactly what you need. That's pretty much what you'd expect since it compiles.

Your problem really has **nothing** to do with the parsing at all. It has to do with how you interpret the correctly parsed negative number, correctly converted to the integer type you chose (`unsigned int`).

Indeed, if you want to treat a `unsigned int` value as a `short` (signed or unsigned) you have to coerce it, or use a bitmask to clear the high bits: `c.number & 0xffff`.

Storing `0xffe7` inside the unsigned int is of course possible. But it is technically just INCORRECT 2's complement encoding. Experience tells me it will lead to error-prone code.

If I were to go for a design like this, I'd choose an integer representation type that is expressly ***NOT an arithmetic type***. Something like

```
struct Number {
     _implementation_defined_ storage;

     uint32_t as_uint32() const { return /*some implementation logic on storage*/; }
     int16_t as_int16() const { return /*some other implementation logic on storage*/; }
     // etc.
};
```

In the land of parsed AST's, I'd prefer

```
template <typename V>
struct Check {
    std::string name;
    V number;
};
using Check = boost::variant<Check<uint32_t>, Check<int16_t>>;
```

With that out of the way, let's see some answers to your question:

### Using static cast in the semantic action

You **can** force the issue using Boost Phoenix: [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8993ea64780d85d6)

```
assign_d_ref %= qi::string("MSG33.D_REF") >> "==" >>
    qi::int_[_1 = boost::phoenix::static_cast_<uint16_t>(_1)];
```

IMO, a slightly better approach¹ is to have a parser that parses uint16_t in the first place:  [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e6e931e01e74c080)

```
qi::int_parser<uint16_t> uint16_;
assign_d_ref = qi::string("MSG33.D_REF") >> "==" >> uint16_;
```

### Other Improvements

I'd also improve the expressiveness some more using e.g.:

```
qi::symbols<char> s16_vars;
s16_vars += "MSG33.D_REF", "MSG34.D_REF";
assign_s16 = qi::raw[s16_vars] >> "==" >> uint16_;
```

To generalize for signed 16 bit variables.

```
qi::rule<It, std::string()> name;
name       = +(qi::alnum | qi::char_("._"));
```

This fixes the missing `lexeme[]` around the name (by declaring the rule without skipper²).

```
assign_u32 = name >> "==" >> qi::uint_;
assign     = assign_s16 | assign_u32;
start      = qi::skip(qi::blank)[assign % "&&" > qi::eoi];
```

Apart from the readability, it fixes the edge case where blanks are immediately before end-of-input.

See the combined result **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4a1d0233e7d92bce)**

```
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

namespace engine {
    struct Check {
        std::string  variable;
        uint32_t     number;

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Check const& c) {
            auto f = os.flags();
            os << "{" << std::quoted(c.variable) << " == " //
               << std::hex << std::showbase << c.number << "}";
            os.setf(f);
            return os;
        }
    };

    using Checks = std::vector<Check>;
} // namespace engine

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(engine::Check, variable, number)

namespace engine {
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

    template <typename It> class Parser : public qi::grammar<It, Checks()> {
      public:
        Parser() : Parser::base_type(start) {
            using namespace qi::labels;

            s16_vars += "MSG33.D_REF", "MSG34.D_REF";
            name       = +(qi::alnum | qi::char_("._"));
            assign_s16 = qi::raw[s16_vars] >> "==" >> uint16_;
            assign_u32 = name >> "==" >> qi::uint_;
            assign     = assign_s16 | assign_u32;
            start      = qi::skip(qi::blank)[assign % "&&" > qi::eoi];

            BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((start)(assign)(assign_u32)(assign_s16)(name))
        }

      private:
        qi::int_parser<uint16_t>              uint16_;
        qi::symbols<char>                     s16_vars;
        qi::rule<It, Check(), qi::blank_type> assign, assign_s16, assign_u32;
        qi::rule<It, Checks()>                start;

        // lexeme:
        qi::rule<It, std::string()> name;
    };

    Checks parse(const std::string& str) {
        using It = std::string::const_iterator;
        static const Parser<It> parser;

        Checks checks;

        It first = str.begin(), last = str.end();
        if (!qi::parse(first, last, parser, checks))
            return {};

        return checks;
    }
} // namespace engine

int main() {
    for (auto sep = ""; auto& c : engine::parse(
             "MSG33.ANYTHING == 25 && MSG33.D_REF == 25 && MSG33.D_REF == -25"))
        std::cout << std::exchange(sep, " && ") << c;
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Printing (like all samples above):

```
{"MSG33.ANYTHING" == 0x19} && {"MSG33.D_REF" == 0x19} && {"MSG33.D_REF" == 0xffe7}
```

### BONUS: Variant Style

Because you might be interested, here's a version using the variant AST:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/92c7dd4b3dba81ad)**

```
#include <boost/core/demangle.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/adapted.hpp>
#include <boost/spirit/include/qi.hpp>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>

namespace engine {
    template <typename T>
    struct VarCheck {
        std::string  variable;
        T            number;

        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, VarCheck const& c) {
            auto f = os.flags();
            os << " {" << std::quoted(c.variable) << " == " << std::hex
               << std::showbase << c.number << ":"
               << boost::core::demangle(typeid(T).name()) << "}";
            os.setf(f);
            return os;
        }
    };
    using S16Var = VarCheck<int16_t>;
    using U32Var = VarCheck<uint32_t>;
    using Check  = boost::variant<U32Var, S16Var>;

    using Checks = std::vector<Check>;
} // namespace engine

// BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(engine::S16Var, variable, number)
// BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(engine::S16Var, variable, number)
// Or, generically: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_80_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/adapted/adapt_tpl_struct.html
BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_TPL_STRUCT((T), (engine::VarCheck)(T), variable, number)

namespace engine {
    namespace qi = boost::spirit::qi;

    template <typename It> class Parser : public qi::grammar<It, Checks()> {
      public:
        Parser() : Parser::base_type(start) {
            using namespace qi::labels;

            s16_vars += "MSG33.D_REF", "MSG34.D_REF";
            name       = +(qi::alnum | qi::char_("._"));
            assign_s16 = qi::raw[s16_vars] >> "==" >> uint16_;
            assign_u32 = name >> "==" >> qi::uint_;
            assign     = assign_s16 | assign_u32;
            start      = qi::skip(qi::blank)[assign % "&&" > qi::eoi];

            BOOST_SPIRIT_DEBUG_NODES((start)(assign)(assign_u32)(assign_s16)(name))
        }

      private:
        qi::int_parser<uint16_t>               uint16_;
        qi::symbols<char>                      s16_vars;
        qi::rule<It, Check(), qi::blank_type>  assign;
        qi::rule<It, U32Var(), qi::blank_type> assign_u32;
        qi::rule<It, S16Var(), qi::blank_type> assign_s16;
        qi::rule<It, Checks()>                 start;

        // lexeme:
        qi::rule<It, std::string()> name;
    };

    Checks parse(const std::string& str) {
        using It = std::string::const_iterator;
        static const Parser<It> parser;

        Checks checks;

        It first = str.begin(), last = str.end();
        if (!qi::parse(first, last, parser, checks))
            return {};

        return checks;
    }
} // namespace engine

int main() {
    for (auto  sep = "";
         auto& c : engine::parse("MSG33.ANYTHING == 25 && MSG33.D_REF == 25 && "
                                 "MSG33.D_REF == -25")) {
        std::cout << std::exchange(sep, "\n && ") << c;
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

I've extended the output with the static type information for visibility:

```
 {"MSG33.ANYTHING" == 0x19:unsigned int}
 &&  {"MSG33.D_REF" == 0x19:short}
 &&  {"MSG33.D_REF" == 0xffe7:short}
```

It's easy to generalize for more variable type here:

```
using S16Var = VarCheck<int16_t>;
using U32Var = VarCheck<uint32_t>;
using DblVar = VarCheck<double>;
using StrVar = VarCheck<std::string>;
using Check  = boost::variant<U32Var, S16Var, DblVar, StrVar>;
```

See it [Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f5c35e2bd72fcc09), with the output

```
 {"MSG33.ANYTHING" == 0x19:unsigned int}
 &&  {"MSG33.D_REF" == 0x19:short}
 &&  {"SEHE.DBL_1" == 4.2e+10:double}
 &&  {"SEHE.DBL_2" == -inf:double}
 &&  {"SEHE.STR_42" == Life The Universe and everything:std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >}
 &&  {"SEHE.STR_300" == Three hundred:std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >}
 &&  {"MSG33.D_REF" == 0xffe7:short}
```

---

¹ E.g. [Boost Spirit: "Semantic actions are evil"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8259440/boost-spirit-semantic-actions-are-evil)

² [Boost spirit skipper issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17072987/boost-spirit-skipper-issues/17073965#17073965)

Comment: All your advices are gold, and also your caution words are noteworthy. Fortunately, this code is done for a tighly close protocol with all its variables and values well defined and non-changing in time, so your non variant solution works great for me! Anyway, thank you for showing me this boost::variant implementation because I was totally unawared about it.